# Wordpress Gallery functionality

Tags: wordpress

I changed the functionality of the Wordpress Gallery. Now when I add a gallery it changes into a slider, each image as a slide. I'm trying to make a Wordpress Theme and my question is:

It is ok to make a function that changes the Gallery into a Slideshow ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In short, no. You should not override the wordpress core's functionality as:

1. These will be overridden in future updates
2. They won't ship with you theme, and users will have to make the same changes.
3. It will be impossible to manage these changes over time.

You are best extending the functionality by implementing such changes into your theme or a custom plugin that you ship with your theme. Here is a good (and humorous) article explaining why this is a bad idea more in depth: http://websynthesis.com/dont-hack-wordpress-core/

Comment: Now that I read my question I understand that I wrote something I didn't mean and that is because of my english. I didn't change the core functions, I made a function that changes the gallery into slideshow. Like a plugin but inside the theme. a function

Comment: I changed the question. I didn't changed the core functions. Just made a function. That's all.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. From your answer I understand that is no problem to make a function. Thanks